# How to find Ron

Tags: voltage, mosfet, current

Compute the effective Ron in the triode region of the v-i characteristic when Vgs = 3V, i.e., measure the current through the MOSFET switch when, say, Vds = 1V
and report Ids/Vds as your answer below. Remember this should be for a device whose W/L is 1.

So I realize you can't just give me the answer, I just wanted to know if there was an equation to find Ron. I haven't learnt it yet, sorry. I only started MOSFETs a week or two ago.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When in doubt, try Ohm's Law...

Comment: You're saying use the MOSFET as a resistor?

Comment: Not so much *use* as *suffer* the fact that a MOSFET *has* resistance.  You are being asked to calculate that resistance at a particular point of operation.  Looking up the meaning of "triode region" would probably help your understanding as well.

Comment: something like K *w/l * Ve, perhaps from differentiating the transconductance

Comment: Yeah, but I can't know K without know ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that a MOSFET can be **modeled** as a resistor for **small** changes in voltage or current. I think it is misleading to say that a MOSFET **has** resistance.

Pick some point on one of the curves you show. Find the slope of that line (actually the tangent of the line) at that point. The slope is \$\Delta I / \Delta V\$, which is \$1/R\$ and \$R\$ is the effective resistance of the MOSFET **at the chosen voltage/current point**. The resistance will obviously be different at different points on the curves.

Of course, this only makes sense for the regions of operation where the current changes as a function of voltage (the **linear** or **triode** region). When the transistor becomes saturated it no longer acts like a resistor, more like a constant current source.

Comment: @WhipStreak23 concepts are infinitely more valuable than equations. If you have a solid understanding of the concepts, equations become rather easy to derive as needed. This answer provides all the needed concepts in this case.

Comment: Not everything in real life (most things actually) will be completely characterized into a into a single nice neat equation. In particular non-linear things, like the curves you have posted above. You could approximate by breaking up the curves into a workable number of sections that are approximately linear with the same slope and assigning a constant R all voltages within that section and swap out as required. The more segments you have, the more accurate but cumbersome it becomes until you reach what a simulation does where it's basically a lookup table.

Comment: @WhipStreak23 The simple equation you are looking for is Ohm's Law.

Comment:  Should have realized that earlier. Thanks Elliot!